# React-table how to change size of column create with hook

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using this code example to create a a custom checkbox column: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v7/examples/row-selection?file=/src/App.js:1667-1692

And it's working fine.

The problem is that I am also using `useFlexLayout` : https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFlexLayout

And it makes by default all the cell have this style inline: `box-sizing: border-box; flex: 150 0 auto; min-width: 0px; width: 150px;`

The good thing is that in the columns definitions it accepts parameters such as `width: 100`, ie:

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
        {
            Header: 'Invoice Number',
            accessor: 'orderNumber',
            width: 100
        },
```

The bad thing is that the column generated by the `hooks.visibleColumns.push` is not defined in `columns = useMemo...` ... and I would like to add a maximum width. Or a `width:30` to override the default 150px.

Anybody knows how can I apply a specific width?

Thank you